# Django - combining form fields with modelform fields

Tags: django-forms

Using Django 1.8, I'm trying to render a form where some of the fields come from the database like the many-to-many field below and some other fields are not in the database at all:

```
models.py
class Transcript(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=65, unique=True)

forms.py
class SummaryForm(forms.Form):
    size = forms.CharField(label='size', max_length=50, required=False)
    transcripts = models.ManyToManyField(Transcript, blank=True)
class Meta:
    widgets = {
        'transcript': autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(url='tr-autocomplete'),
    }
```

Why on my template page I do not see transcripts rendered and how to render it?

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
transcripts = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label='Transcript', required=False)
```